# How get printer MIB commands

Tags: snmp, mib

I have printer `HP Color LaserJet CP5520`. I try find mib for this devices, but not found it. I try use other hp devices mib but its not correct work.

How get all mib of printer? Is there snmp command that get all printer mib-s?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **HP-LASERJET-COMMON-MIB** to monitor your printer. This MIB file can be downloaded from http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Files/HP-LASERJET-COMMON-MIB.mib

Also most of HP printers do support standard **PRINTER-MIB** defined in **RFC1759**.

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming it's implemented correctly, you can retrieve an SNMP agent's sysORTable to obtain a list of OIDs (by sysORID) identifying the modules that the agent supports and a brief description (by sysORDescr) of those modules. You can use these to track down the proper MIB modules to load into your manager from the vendor and/or public MIB search engine.